# Debugging xslt file in visual studio 2010

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xslt

I am debugging an xslt file in vs 2010, and at first I was prompted to link to a xml source file. However, now I want to use a different source file. How can I get the xslt to point to a different xml source file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

make sure your xslt file is in active then go to view > properties window then you can change the input file!

Comment: your welcome, the Visual Studio interface can be somewhat daunting :P

Answer (score 1):

**You can specify the source XML file for the transformation in the properties window** for the XSLT file. The `input` property should contain the path to the XML file to be processed. Enter the path to the new XML file here.

**An XSLT transformation can process simultaneously more than one XML document**.

This is achieved by using the [**`document()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function, or by passing an XML document as **[a parameter to the transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-param)**.

You may need to enable the `document()` function using the **[`XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction.aspx)** property.

Read **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx)** how to pass parameters to an XSLT transformation.

Comment: Previously, a dislog box popped up to point to the source xml file. How do I get that dialog box to show up again?